# Applied filter is not persisted on AdminJs application

Tags: typescript, adminjs

I'm currently exploring the AdminJs application by SoftwareBrothers and issue/blocker which i'm facing is that when we apply any filter to any products, the list of products with the applied filters are displayed and when user edit any of the products and click on "Save" button, the applied filter would be gone and user is navigated to the default list page.!

Is there a way to make the filter persist even after the user edit a product and click on "Save"?

> I tried using ComponentLoader and override the default edit action
> I even tried to stop the redirection after user clicks on save button , but none worked for me

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.